# From a collection of N points in 3D, find the collection of M points that have most unique points within a distance, d

Tags: python

I have a collection of several thousand (N) "systems" with associated coordinates in 3D, structured as:

```
universe = [[sys1_ID, sys1_Name, sys1_XCoord, sys1_YCoord, sys1_ZCoord],
            [sys2_ID, sys2_Name, sys2_XCoord, sys2_YCoord, sys2_ZCoord],
                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
            [sysN_ID, sysN_Name, sysN_XCoord, sysN_YCoord, sysN_ZCoord]]
```

I would like to be able to find the best possible selection of M of these systems, such that a maximum number of unique systems lie within some distance, d, of at least one of the M systems.

The distance here being the usual Euclidean-norm, so for systems 1 and 2:

```
xDelta = sys1_XCoord - sys2_XCoord
yDelta = sys1_YCoord - sys2_YCoord
zDelta = sys1_ZCoord - sys2_ZCoord
d = sqrt( xDelta ** 2 + yDelta ** 2 + zDelta ** 2 )
```

To this end, I have produced a dictionary with key equal to the system name and value as a list of all other systems within a distance, d, of that system name. Structured as:

```
withinRange_Dict = {sys1_Name : list_of_systems_in_range_of_sys1,
                    sys2_Name : list_of_systems_in_range_of_sys2,
                                         .
                                         .
                                         .
                    sysN_Name : list_of_systems_in_range_of_sysN}
```

For the trivial case of M = 1, I simply need to select the key whose value has the largest length.

What would you recommend as an approach if M is 2 or higher? Is there a better approach than trying every combination of M systems and finding the combination whose value union has greatest length? If that is the best option, is there a recommended pythonic route to go down?